# Can i use my old electric water heater electrical supply wire to power new outlets?

Tags: electrical

I removed an electric hot water heater and replaced it with a gas unit.

Can I use the 10 gauge 30 amp line to install 3 outside outlets and how to do it.

Comment: 10 gauge will not fit most regular(15 or 20A) outlets.  It is too big.  Can change 30 amp breaker to a 15 or 20 amp breaker and use 14 or 12 gauge cable.

Comment: Yes, you can. But use GFCI receptacles. Breaker protect wires from overheating for fire safety.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can, but for normal 120v outlets, you'll need to swap the 240 volt/30 amp breaker for a 120v 20 amp,  I suggest a "DUFI" if available for your panel.  DUFIs are industry slang for Dual function breakers.  They actually do 4 things:  1) Normal over-current protection, 2) Ground Fault protection, 3) Series arc fault protection and 4) parallel arc fault protection. You'll need to get filler plate to block off the space since the 120 v breaker will be taking 1 slot whereas the 240 took two.

Depending upon your jurisdiction, only GFCI may be required for outdoor outlets. But AFCI isn't a bad thing.   Others here (with more knowledge than me) favor using GFCI breakers in panels rather than GFCI outlets, the reasoning is they are protected from the weather, by being installed in a panel and last a lot longer.

OK, that aside said, moving on:  At the box where the old water heater was, run 12/2 from there to your outdoor outlets. Use high quality outlets, not $.79 cheapies.
You'll install the white wire that is now the neutral to the GFCI breaker (assuming you go that route), and the white pig-tail from the breaker to the neutral bus bar.  If you choose to use a GFCI outlet "first in line" for your outdoor outlets, you'll need to move the white wire that was formally connected to the water heater breaker to the neutral bus bar.  Mark the 10ga wires with a tag saying there is 12ga as part of that circuit. Any decent electrician would probably realize that, but a future homeowner might not. No penalty for clarity!

I'd like to see a pic of the inside of your main panel to see exactly what we are dealing with.  Brand and age of panel also helps.  Based on that, I may update my answer.

**CAVEAT:**  What I responded with is what is a "typical" install, if you have something more unique, your mileage my vary.  Again, shoot us a pic of the innards and we can be more sure.

Comment: "DUFI"  ... they do four things and cost 8 times as much....... +1

Comment: @JACK   LOL, YEAH, I agree. Regular breaker at $5.00, AFCI or GFCI at about $40 and DUFIs at about $50. I think some manufacturers influenced the NEC writers....really drives up the cost of a loaded panel.   And now, the 2020 NEC is requiring GFCI protection on EVERYTHING:  Electric water heaters, furnaces, heat pumps, clothes dryers....I can agree with outdoor GFCI and indoor in "wet" locations like bathrooms and kitchens.  But proper grounding has been adequate a very long time. I think GFCI protection on everything is overkill.  +

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your old wire to the water heater was black-white-bare.  Right now, the white wire is supposed to be marked with black tape and attached to the hot leg of a 30A breaker.  It should be moved to the neutral bar for 120V.

The black wire should be moved from a 30A breaker to either a 20A or 15A.  Use 20A if you intend to extend the circuit with #12 wire, otherwise use a 15A if you intend to extend with any #14.

I don't even own any #14 wire.  #12 is the universal donor, works on both 15A and 20A circuits, and industry pricing is "the bigger the spool the cheaper it is per foot".  So I find it better use of my money to buy only #12. If I was laying 500 feet of wire a day I might feel different.

Install a junction box at the water heater end of the cable if there isn't one already.  In that junction box, use red or tan wire nuts to splice from the #10 to #12/14 wire(s).

Comment: Harp:  if the OP is going to use a GFCI breaker, rather than a GFCI outlet, the white #10 (hopefully code taped like you said and needs to be removed), would need to go to the breaker and the white pig-tail connected to the neutral bus bar. I did mention this in my answer above.